# MSDN reference API's

Tags: windows, windows-8, msdn

Does anyone know if there are web api's that allow you to retrieve MSDN info from a webservice call? Unfortunately googling MSDN web API's returns information on how to use web API's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really not very easy to find, I agree...

http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/ContentService.asmx

From the intro:

> This is the documentation for the MSDN/TechNet Publishing System
>   (MTPS) Content Service. The MTPS Content Service is an XML web service
>   that provides access to the content stored in MTPS. This includes, for
>   example, the content available at http://msdn2.microsoft.com/library.
>   Using the MTPS Content Service, developers can integrate
>   documentation, technical articles, whitepapers, images and the other
>   content available from the MTPS system into their own applications.

Comment: And if you need to generate code stubs or to process the formal WSDL description file in any other way which fails because it is invalid, then have a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598324/msdn-web-service-wsdl-not-parsing).