# MSDN web service WSDL not parsing

Tags: web-services, wsdl, webservice-client, msdn

I am trying to create a web services client for Microsoft's MSDN service ([MSTP Content Service](http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/ContentService.asmx)). When I use my local IDE to generate the classes it is failing to parse the WSDL from Microsoft published at http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/ContentService.asmx?wsdl and so I tried validating it with a "neutral" validator ([XMethods WSDL Validator](http://xmethods.net/ve2/Tools.po)) and the XMethods validator is saying it cannot parse it with no further significant information. I also tried the [eXtc validator](http://www.validwsdl.com/) and got a similar parse failure. How can I get past this error and create a web services client for MSTP?

Comment: The support on [link](http://escde.net) may help you with this. I need stubs for this Content Service, too, and just contacted Microsoft about this issue. I will post the result in your question as soon as they answered me. Did you find any solution in the meantime?

Comment: They answered me, now: Since they don't have access to the sources they cannot correct them. With code stub generator tools from Visual Studio it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I needed code stubs in order to communicate with the MS Content Service System. I used Apache CXF which provides tools for generation of Java or Corba stubs. Apache CXF failed because of a misspelled attribute (`"messsage"` with 3 s instead of 2):

```
...
<wsoap12:header messsage="this:AppID" part="AppID" user="literal"/>
...
```

A download of the formal description file (and correction of misspelled attribute name) wasn't successful because there are further files required for stub generation. I download all missing 14 files.

You could download the WSDL description file and execute the Apache CXF stub generation on this file. This script will abort and print the missing file. So, you have to download this file, manually, and to restart the generation which may abort several times because of further missing files. You can find this files in the `schemas` folder on the web server, e.g.:

```
http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/schemas/urn_mtpg_com_mtps_2004_1_image_category_atoms.xsd
http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/schemas/urn_msdn_com_public_content_syndication_2006_09_common.xsd
...
```

Repeatedly download them and put them into a schemas folder near your WSDL description file.